# Where can I download high quality images of poker cards?

Tags: playing-cards, poker

I am looking for high quality images of poker cards to download. I can use Google Images to download the images, but it would be impossible to find 53 identical cards in terms of style (52 cards + 1 joker card). Does anybody know where can I get these images from?

Comment: I all reality the look of the fronts of the cards are almost irrelevant -- you could just have a child's drawing on them. What's super important though is that the backs look exactly alike to the pixel. That won't be trivial with a home printer, for example because of alignment issues.

Comment: If you want to use these images for anything other than a personal project that you're not distributing to anyone or putting on the internet, you might also have to worry about licensing. You can't just freely reuse any image you find on the internet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Googling for 'SVG cards' gives some results, including [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/svg-cards/files/) which is also featured on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card#/media/File:Svg-cards-2.0.svg).

[image]
(created by David Bellot)

Comment: This set lacks the suicide king and has only 1 one-eyed jack (and it's the wrong one, should be hearts and spades). There are some games and rules it won't work for.

Comment: @Separatrix. Just curious : do you have some example of rules for which you'd need the cards you mention? Are those relevant to poker?

Comment: @EricDuminil they're sometimes wild in draw poker for example. Sometimes all the one eyed royals are wild. Mostly you can make them up as you go along but they're conventions.

Answer (score 29):

The deck linked by @Glorfindel is for French playing cards.

Here's a [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/vector-playing-cards/) to poker playing cards, in [PNG](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/vector-playing-cards/PNG-cards-1.3.zip) or [SVG](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/vector-playing-cards/SVG-cards-1.3.zip) format.

Poker cards are wider than French ones. This design is used by many decks, e.g. [Bicycle Playing Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_Playing_Cards), and will typically be the one you see in movies or at the casino.

[image: King of hearts]

> A full set of poker playing cards created using vector graphics. The
>   .SVG source for each card is available as well as a high resolution
>   rasterized .PNG version. These images are released into the public
>   domain - attribution is appreciated but not required.

Here's the related blog post : [Byron's Blog - Vector Playing Cards](http://byronknoll.blogspot.com/2011/03/vector-playing-cards.html)

As mentioned by @Dezza, there  are other alternatives:

> There's also SVG sets by revk at [me.uk/cards](https://www.me.uk/cards/) with associated blog
>   posts [revk.uk/search/label/Playing%20cards](https://www.revk.uk/search/label/Playing%20cards)

Comment: What's the difference between French playing cards and poker cards here?

Comment: @ilkkachu : The design is different. Note that you can play poker with French playing cards just fine. In movies or at the casino, you'll probably see poker cards : https://youtu.be/5VC7BuWahBM?t=64

Comment: There's also SVG sets by revk at https://www.me.uk/cards/ with associated blog posts https://www.revk.uk/search/label/Playing%20cards

Comment: @Dezza: It looks good, thanks. I updated my answer.

Comment: @ilkkachu The letters on the royal cards may also be different.  "R", "D", and "V", instead of "K", "Q", and "J".  (Stands for "Roi", "Dame", and "Valet")

Comment: @DarrelHoffman & Eric, yeah, I was just wondering because apart from the art of the face cards, Glorfindel's set looks pretty much like this one :) The artwork here is the one I've most commonly seen, so perhaps more standard in a way. I thought I've also heard the "standard" cards being called French playing cards and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck) does seem to at least imply a connection too, mentioning "a standard 52-card deck of French playing cards". Though of course you could have shorter decks with the French suits and similar images, too.

Comment: All of these cards are French; that refers to the suits and basic design. The cards that are narrower than Poker cards are Bridge cards.

Comment: @MarkReed Thanks a lot, I didn't know that. I guess I was referring to [*Paris pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French-suited_playing_cards#Paris_pattern), then?

Answer (score 4):

In 2018, I created a W3C standard **Custom Element** `<card-t suit=Hearts rank=Queen></card-t>`

CardMeister does **not** ***load*** SVG, it ***creates*** SVG client-side.

All 52 cards SVG is optimized, contained in one Custom Element file:

**16 KB** download in the cheating version.
**64 KB** download in the full version, with spades and hearts *one eyed jacks*, hearts *suicide king*.

**CardMeister Demo:** https://cardmeister.github.io/

**Github & Documentation:** https://github.com/cardmeister/cardmeister.github.io

**only HTML required is**:

```
<head>
    <script src="elements.cardmeister.full.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <card-t suit=Hearts rank=Queen></card-t>
</body>
```

[image]

SVG is based on the CC0-licensed Card Generator by Adrian Kennard: https://www.me.uk/cards/

[image]

Because SVG is created client-side, there are s-loads of options to design playing-cards:

[image]

playingcards **https://cardmeister.github.io/**

SVG Card Web Component

Comment: Please note that if this is your work, [you should make this very clear in your answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking in adding cards to a text that you write in **LaTeX** then the `pst-poker` package is useful, see http://web.mit.edu/foley/games/Arcadia/sr/poker/poker-doc.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For those searching for playing card images, I have produced a complete pack that uses a variation on the standard design of pips. [The SVG playing cards](https://tekeye.uk/playing_cards/svg-playing-cards) I have made are a full deck (52 cards + Jokers) and card backs.

[image: Ace of Spades]

Plus PNG images available from the article at https://tekeye.uk/playing_cards/svg-playing-cards

Answer (score 0):

Here

https://www.me.uk/cards/makeadeck.cgi

I was looking for a 4-color plain poker deck and was able to generate one. Many other options for SVG playing cards.